# Is there any way to get a warning in eg. GCC or Clang about this strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

The rationale for this being a strict aliasing violation is that
the buffer has declared type char array and is being aliased by
a pointer to struct

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdalign.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct thing {
  int a;
  char x;
};

int main() {
  char alignas(struct thing) buffer[128];
  
  struct thing s = {10,'a'};

  struct thing *ptr = memcpy(buffer,&s,sizeof(struct thing));
  
  // violation at ptr->a
  printf("%d\n",ptr->a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strict aliasing violations can't be detected statically in general.

Comment: @Barmar Here, it can be deduced that `ptr` is comes from `&s` via memcpy, and so points to `s`.  Furthermore, `ptr->a` is accessed in the same basic block where `s.a` is assigned; data flow analysis readily shows that the last store to `ptr->a` was actually to `s.a`.  Maybe GCC simply doesn't trace pointer provenance through `memcpy`. Code that uses the return value of `memcpy` at all is pretty rare.

Comment: Does it make a difference if, instead of using the return value of `memcpy`, you ignore the return value of the memcpy and then initialize `ptr` directly from `&s`, with a cast? The purpose of this question is to determine whether this is the issue: not tracing the pointer data flow through the memcpy function.

Comment: @kaz for the record I am not able to find a way to get any warnings when doing like so either   
  `struct thing *ptr = (struct thing*) &buffer[0];
  ptr->a = 10;
  ptr->x = 'a';`

Comment: @anonymouscoward, the warning is generated when `buffer` is not an array, interesting...

Answer (score 2):

A compiler that warned about all constructs that violate the constraints in N1570 6.5p7 as written would generate a lot of warnings about constructs which all quality implementations would support without difficulty.  The only way those parts of the Standard would make any sense would be if the authors expected quality implementations to extend the semantics of the language to support use cases which, even if they're not mandated by the Standard, they should have no reason not to support.  The use case illustrated in the presented code is an example of this.

Although the Standard would not forbid implementations from using N1570 6.5p7 as an excuse to behave nonsensically even in situations where an object is only ever used as a single type of storage, the stated purpose of the rules is to describe situations where implementations would or would not be required to allow for the possibility of pointer aliasing.  Forbidding the particular construct at issue *even in cases where storage is only used as a single type* would do nothing to further that aim.  If code were to use the subscripting operator on `buffer`, in addition to accessing the storage via a `struct thing*`, a compiler might legitimately fail to recognize the possibility that accesses using the latter lvalue might interact with those using the former.  In the presented code, however, the storage is only used as type `struct thing` or via `memcpy`, usage cases that there would have been no reason to prohibit.  Writing the rules in such a way as to only forbid use of a `char[]` to hold data of some other type in situations where it was also subscripted would definitely add complexity, but would not have been expected to make compilers support any constructs they wouldn't have supported anyway.

If the Standard had been intended to characterize programs into those that were correct or incorrect, it would need to have been worthwhile to write more detailed rules.  Since it made no attempt to distinguish constructs which are erroneous from those which are correct but "non-portable" (in the sense that there might exist some implementations which don't process them meaningfully), however, there was no need to try to explicitly identify and provide for all of the constructs which compilers would have no reason not to process meaningfully.